# Testing the effect of a variable with ANOVA or Chi Square

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, mean, count-data

In order to assess the reliability of a self-recording system, I want to check the effect of the day of the week on the biological phenomenon I study. Apart from the habits and convenience of the users, there is no reason at all the day of the week would have any effect on the recording of the aformentioned phenomenenon. Two options:

1) Consider the mean number of occurences by day, each day being therefore similar to a treatment group and subsequently perform an ANOVA;

2) Count every occurences for each day and compare observed occurences with expected ones using a Chi square test;

[image]

Problem: In some subgroups both ANOVA and Chi² are significant (fig. A), whereas in other subgroups only Chi² reveals differences in the day by day distribution (fig. B, H0 is rejected for mondays and wednesdays but there is no differences between days by ANOVA).

NB: the biological phenomenon I study is not evenly through the year. 
I am worried ANOVA could hide differences still Chi square seems very strict given the large number of data points I have to process.

What would be the best option to deal with this problem ?

Comment: For a given day, you have a dichotomous variable being number of occurrences vs number of non-occurrences. What is the other variable?

Comment: That's it; for a given day I have let's say a number of deaths within my population, provided that the annual death toll remains stable. Question is: "are mondays associated with a higher mortality rate ?"